# Differentiability of a maximizer function

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable. The problem $\max_{x\in[0,1]}f(ax+b,x)$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers) has a solution $x(a,b)$ for each $(a,b)$. Will the map $a\mapsto x(a,b)$ be differentiable for each $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $b=0$ and $f(x,y) = x$.  The $x \in [0,1]$ that maximizes $f(ax,x) = ax$ is $0$ for $a < 0$ and $1$ for $a > 0$, while all $x \in [0,1]$ are maximizers for $a=0$.  There is no choice of $x(0,0)$ that makes this a continuous function, let alone differentiable.